# How can I filter an array on an asynchronous predicate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, promise, async-await

I have an array of `users` and I want to grab a subset of them based on an inexpensive lookup in a redis set.

```js
const users = [
  { _id: '1', name: 'george', age: 36 },
  { _id: '2', name: 'henry', age: 33 },
  { _id: '3', name: 'agatha', age: 28 },
  { _id: '4', name: 'janet', age: 29 },
  { _id: '5', name: 'gary', age: 21 },
  // ... 995 more users
]

const db = {/* my redis connection */}

const isInside = (db, user) => {
  return db.contains('my:set:key', user._id)
}
```

I have tried `Array.prototype.filter` but it doesn't seem to work

```js
users.filter(user => isInside(db, user))
// => always gives me back all the users even when I see they are not in the set
```

I know something is wrong here. How do I filter out users using `isInside`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `filter` is always synchronous and your DB calls are asynchronous, filter function always returns `true` because its `db.contains` is a running promise, so it converts to `true`.

One of the solutions could be, to create an array of promises, wait for all of them, and then filter out.

```
const users = [
  { _id: '1', name: 'george', age: 36 },
  { _id: '2', name: 'henry', age: 33 },
  { _id: '3', name: 'agatha', age: 28 },
  { _id: '4', name: 'janet', age: 29 },
  { _id: '5', name: 'gary', age: 21 },
  // ... 995 more users
]

const dbCheck = users.map(user => isInside(db, user))

Promise.all(dbCheck).then((values) => {
  // here you have array of bools [true, false ...]

  const filteredUsers = users.filter((_, index) => values[index]))
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will probably be OK with `Promise.all(users.map(user => isInside(db, user)))` but there's a danger of hitting the database too hard with multiple simultaneous requests, particularly with some 3rd-party cloud services.

If so, then you can orchestrate an asynchronous filter in which db queries are performed sequentially, based on [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

It's a bit of a palaver, but not too bad:

```js
const users = [
   { _id: '1', name: 'george', age: 36 },
   { _id: '2', name: 'henry', age: 33 },
   { _id: '3', name: 'agatha', age: 28 },
   { _id: '4', name: 'janet', age: 29 },
   { _id: '5', name: 'gary', age: 21 },
   // ... 995 more users
]

users.reduce(function(promise, user) {
 return promise
 .then(arr => {
  return isInside(null, user) // <<< the asynchronous call
  .then(bool => { // isInside delivers Boolean
   if(bool) arr.push(user); // act, depending on asynchronously derived Boolean
   return arr; // deliver arr to next iteration of the reduction
  });
 });
}, Promise.resolve([])) // starter promise, resolved to empty array
.then(filtered => {
 console.log(filtered); // Yay! a filtered array
});

// dummy isInside() function
function isInside(db, user) {
 return Promise.resolve(Math.random() < 0.5); // 50% probability
}
```

Of course, this will be slower than a `.map()` solution but if `.map()` doesn't work ....

Comment: Can quite eacily be rephrased as a method on `Array.prototype`.